# SquirrelMail does not show the INBOX

Tags: squirrelmail

SquirrelMail does not show the INBOX but for only 1 user.

For all other users it works OK.
I guess it must be something user specific... maybe something in his ~HOME or in any other place SquirrelMail keeps user-related files.

The thing is that in his ~HOME I did not see anything... suspicious...

Any ideas?

Comment: Check permissions, always.

Comment: Already done that. ~HOME permissions are OK (all the dir-tree has the same permissions (not ownership of course!) as a working user). Is there another folder that I need to see?

Comment: You said `For all other users it works OK`, just compare directories between them. `ls -laZ` of both folders on split terminals and you'll see it :)

Comment: As I said, I did that for the ~HOME dir. ALL ~HOME dir/tree permissions are exactly the same (save the ownership). Is there another place I should look?

Comment: As an additional step, I deleted all (.* and *) the ~HOME user files and replace them with the files from another user (did a chown -R username), but still nothing...

Comment: If the folder where you storage mails is inside the home of each user, that's all. Then, have a look at the logs while accessing and while restarting the service.

Comment: Nothing... I ended up making a new user... (checked again all the files, but found no difference... weird...)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a similar problem. SquirrelMail 1.4 is increasingly unable to show certain multi-part emails in the inbox, though it shows in the unread count.  A workaround I finally discovered is click 'search', and enter @ (no quotes or backslashes) to search in Inbox.  It will give a reverse sorted list, newest on the bottom.